# if M is a cv::Mat, why will M.col(1) = M.col(7) not work?

Tags: c++, opencv

If M is a cv::Mat , the following codes will work:

> Mat M1 = M.col(1);
>
> M.col(7).copyTo(M1);

But this will not:

> M.col(1) = M.col(7)

why?

> Update:
> I found the explanation provided by official doc:
> [cv::Mat::row()](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-row)

Comment: This is all about references. M.col(i) just provides a reference rather than than value itself. Read this, look out for copyto,  http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-copyto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use:

```
M.col(7).copyTo(M.col(1));
```

copyTo function copy the data from one matrix to another (i.e. perform deep copy). Operator "equal", on the other hand, only copy one pointer to another (i.e. perform shallow copy).

And M.col() is a constant point that can't be reassigned anyway.

Comment: thank you very much. Btw,for `cv::Mat b=a.row(1)`; , if the `data` field is the same, what is the difference between `a` and `b` ?

Comment: If 'a' is a matrix m*n, than 'b' is a matrix 1*n. 'b' will be an alias for the first row of 'a'. Changing the data in one of them will change the data in other. Mat is actually a smart pointer and this is how pointers in C++ work.

Comment: thx..But what I really want to know is the difference in the two instances of `cv::Mat`,if their `data` field is the same, how can other functions know they are different cv::Mat with different sizes?

Comment: Michael, I found that your last statement may be wrong. I have checked the header file `mat.inl.hpp`,`cv::Mat::col()` is defined as this : `Mat Mat::col(int x) const`,it returns a non-const header.

Comment: @alexyangfox, try to resize it or change it in any other way.

Answer (score 0):

As your link to the [docs of cv::Mat::row](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a4b22e1c23af7a7f2eef8fa478cfa7434) is broken, here the excerpt:

> In the current implementation, the following code does not work as
> expected:

```
Mat A; ... A.row(i) = A.row(j); // will not work
```

> This
> happens because A.row(i) forms a temporary header that is further
> assigned to another header. Remember that each of these operations is
> O(1), that is, no data is copied. Thus, the above assignment is not
> true if you may have expected the j-th row to be copied to the i-th
> row. To achieve that, you should either turn this simple assignment
> into an expression or use the Mat::copyTo method:

```
Mat A;
...
// works, but looks a bit obscure.
A.row(i) = A.row(j) + 0;
// this is a bit longer, but the recommended method.
A.row(j).copyTo(A.row(i));
```

**Summary**

So long story short: `A.row(i)` and `A.row(j)` are `headers`. You can not assign a header to a header. `A.row(j) + 0` is an `expression` however. When you assign an expression to a header, the data is copied, where it belongs to.